# Alternative for deprecated ViewModelProviders?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm, viewmodelproviders

[According to that Medium article here,](https://medium.com/@marco_cattaneo/android-viewmodel-and-factoryprovider-good-way-to-manage-it-with-dagger-2-d9e20a07084c) I am using the `ViewModelProviders` accordingly:

```
myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, this.viewModeFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

deprecated for me currently:

> ```
> @deprecated Use the 'by viewModels()' Kotlin property delegate or
>
>  @link ViewModelProvider#ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner)},
>  passing in the fragment.
> ```

In that article ViewModels with possible constructor arguments have a workaround where it implements the `ViewModelProvider.Factory` and its overridden function `override fun create(//..)` to provide different ViewModel arguments in a Map with Dagger.

Since I would like to learn modern technologies, I am looking for some examples with the proposed solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
myViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, this.viewModeFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```